2000s creepy independant film with a voice-over of a radio host giving bad self-help advice
I remember watching an independent psychological horror movie during the 2000s or maybe early 2010s in Strasbourg (France), during either the Festival Européen du Film Fantastique de Strasbourg (FEFFS), or the earlier Étrange Festival (Strasbourg edition), but browsing the FEFFS' movie list yielded nothing.
What I remember about the film:

Full-length psychological horror movie
Language was English, probably American English
The image had a yellowish tint that evoked dryness
The film was set in a silent, creepy, derelict, dirty, probably American suburb
The plot was about a young couple (no child, IIRC) moving into said suburb
The neighbors were all creepy, such as crippled, half or fully crazy. Some kept rotting food/maggots in glass jars, IIRC.
There was a voice-over that was a radio show, where people would call and explain their issue (e.g. unable to communication with their mom), and the host would give advice… but it was the worst kind, such as "Your mother did not want you, and that's why she told you all these words. You're not loved, and should take revenge on her", or similar.


Could it have been Neighborhood Watch a.k.a. Deadly End from 2005?
A young, childless couple, Bob and Wendi, move to a suburban town, where they encounter weird and creepy neighbours. There lives a deaf couple across the street, and one of their next-door neighbours, Adrien Trumbull, has a knack for poisons and keeps trying to poison them, among other things by giving them a box of poisoned chocolates.
The neighbourhood looks decrepit and empty:








Adrien's house is filled with jars and tins full of unidentifiable stuff:








At the neighbour's house, the radio is always on and tuned in to some extremist Christian channel (e.g. "..disease of the soul, can only be cured by spiritual warfare; God's nuclear bomb..". At some point you can overhear the following conversation, which comes very close to your example:


..but they said if I don't do the injections, I could get gangrene, or go blind!
Do it then, show them how weak and spineless you really are, and drink their ..damn hemlock. Hehe.
What should I do?
First, get rid of that insulin, throw it away. It's poison to your body..


It's not particularly yellow, though, but maybe that had to do with how and where you saw it. However, there is a yellow lit scene with a monologue by that same neighbor that might have left an impression.
Here is the Rotten Tomatoes page for it.

Thanks @Joachim! This ticks so many boxes, however neither title rings any bell. I'll blame my faulty memory and try to watch it!

I've accepted your answer as I probably won't be able to rewatch that movie anytime soon. Thanks again! ;-)
